# Lotus Notes Agent to forward an email on a button press

Tags: lotus-notes

I would like to add a butoon to the toolbar in Lotus Notes that performs the following actions when clicked on:

- Forward the selected email (in preview pane), cc'ing the sender of the original email, and with some standard text cc'd into the body of the email.

Any advice on where to start with this would be much appreciated.  I have been trying to work it out from the Notes user guide but am not getting very far.

Thanks very much,

Rob.

Comment: Rob, did it work for you? If no, please tell what doesn't work. If yes, please set answer to "accepted" so that your question appears outside as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Create a new toolbar button clicking `File\Preferences...\Toolbar\Customize\New\Button...` and 
use for toolbar button this formula:

```
_From := @Text(From);
@Command([MailForward]);
@Command([EditNextField]);
@Command([EditInsertText]; _From);
@Command([EditGotoField]; "Body");
@Command([EditInsertText]; "Your text" + @NewLine + "goes here...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Environment Variable fwdID - it is set in the Actions to Forward mails. This ID refers to the current mail i.e. the "forwarded mail". Using this variable you can get any values from the "source" document and enter these values into the new (forward) mail - e.g. use LotusScript in the PostOpen Event of the Memo-Form.

Attention: the ID remains in the notes-ini until the next forwarding action. Therefore you either set it to "" in your source or you have to proove that not any new memo receives the values from the one mail you forwarded days ago...