# Copy and send using @commands in lotus notes

Tags: email, command, lotus-notes

I'm trying to create a button in the toolbar of a Lotus Notes mail-file that will forward the currently selected documwent to a mail-address while setting a field.
I need to to this by using @commands, as I will not be allowed to change the design of the database. I've been playing around with @mailsend, etc etc, but I don't come to a real solution here :-)

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: how you like to forward the document? as doc link?

Comment: Nope, I would like the full document to be send. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344710/lotus-notes-agent-to-forward-an-email-on-a-button-press but this still asks for a second action by the user. I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can forward the document with

```
@Command( [MailForwardAsAttachment] )
```

than the Document will be forwarded to the address which is in the 'SendTo' field of the selected document. So if the sendTo field not exist, you have to created the field like this

```
FIELD SendTo:= "person@mail.com" ; 
@Command( [MailForwardAsAttachment] )
```

and for this you have to be the editor of the document.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I would have thought the mail would be "attached" as a file-attachment, but this appears not to be the case.